# Removing HTML Tags from meta property in Laravel directly in views

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-views

I am a loading a variable in Laravel which has some paragraph tags for the **meta property"og:description"**. Is there a way I can remove the paragraph tag directly from the views>x.blade.php

Example:

```
<p> Hello Work </p>
```

should appear as:

```
Hello World
```

Any helps is always appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that using `strip_tags` function. You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

You can prepare your variable in the controller and then pass it into blade, or just use it directly in blade like this:

```html
{{ strip_tags($yourString) }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great and it worked! Just a quick add on - do you know how I would remove empty white space (not the spaces between my description)?

Comment: For that, you would be able to use `str_replace` - here is the reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

`str_replace(' ', $yourString)` - if that's what you are looking for.